# From a true vacuum to a false vacuum in expanding space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

It is known that spacetime expansion affects many aspects in the universe. For instance, due to this, a global definition of energy conservation is difficult to define.

Could this expansion affect the vacuum of the universe and its energy density and transform it to a metastable/false vacuum somehow (even if we found ourselves to be in a true vacuum)?

Comment: If by "true vacuum" you mean the lowest energy state of some time evolution in this expanding spacetime, then, by definition, it is dynamically stable. Are you instead asking what happens if we start at the vacuum state of a static universe and at a later time begin the expansion?

Comment: It is actually worse than that. GR predicts that an empty universe "flies apart" infinitely fast (there are no stable volume elements at all). I heard a talk by Kip S. Thorne once where he strongly urged the audience not to think about spacetime as some sort of fabric but as analogous to the flow of water. Near gravitating bodies space was constantly flowing "into" the bodies, far away it was constantly flowing away from them.  In that sense there is no such thing as a "stable" vacuum. The vacuum is only stabilized by the stress-energy of its own matter.